# React Hooks ref.current is undefined during test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-hooks

TLDR - I have a responsive component using ref.current.offsetWidth but it doesn't work when I test it with Jest

The navbar component works and renders fine in localhost. But when I'm trying to stimulate different screen widths using Jest for unit testing, the ref hook is unable to pick up div length for some reason. Any suggestion on how to fix this?

Error:  `TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of undefined`

Code: Navbar.js

```
// custom hook to get live div width 
const useContainerDimensions = myRef => {
  const getDimensions = () => ({
    width: myRef.current.offsetWidth,            //location of error
  });

  const [dimensions, setDimensions] = useState({ width: 0 });

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleResize = () => {
      setDimensions(getDimensions());
    };
    if (myRef.current) {
      setDimensions(getDimensions());
    }

    window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
    };
  }, [myRef]);

  return dimensions;
};

const Navbar = () => {
  const inputRef = useRef();
  const { width } = useContainerDimensions(inputRef);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (width >= 890) {
      setCurrTabPerRow(5);
      setTabStyle('5 tabs');
    }
    if (width < 890) {
      setCurrTabPerRow(4);
      setTabStyle('4 tabs');
    }
  }, [width]);

  return (
    ... 
    <div ref={inputRef}>
      //...stuff
    </div>
    ...
  )
}

export default Navbar;
```

navbar.test.js

```
const resizeWindow = (x, y) => {
  window.innerWidth = x;
  window.innerHeight = y;
  window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
}

describe('Navbar component', () => {
  it('should render', () => {
    const component = mount(
      <Navbar filter>
        <Navbar.Tab id="stuff1" />
        <Navbar.Tab id="stuff2" />
        <Navbar.Tab id="stuff3" />
      </Navbar>
    );
    act(() => {
      resizeWindow(500, 300);
    });
    expect(component).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The initial value of the ref is undefined. You can simply check that the `myRef.current` exists before accessing further properties. and provide a fallback value.

```
const getDimensions = () => ({
  width: (myRef.current && myRef.current.offsetWidth) || 0,
});
```

or with optional chaining

```
const getDimensions = () => ({
  width: myRef?.current?.offsetWidth || 0,
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The useRef hook initially has no value. You're passing the `inputRef` right after declaring it.

Try to do something like this:

```js
const [containerWidth, setContainerWidth] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
  if(inputRef.current) {
    const { width } = useContainerDimensions(inputRef);

    setContainerWidth(width);
  }
}, [inputRef])
```

Then you make sure that the `inputRef` has some value before passing to your custom hook.